# Decrease work_mem on Postgresql and query got faster, why?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

Looking at the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) it seems that the more work_mem the better since "... generally be allowed to use as much memory as this value specifies before it starts to write data into temporary files". Which I understand as bad.

But trying to measure the improvement when increaseing this value I set it to the lowest possible, 64kB, but the query got faster, how come?!?

query explain with 64MB of work_mem:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Unique  (cost=325.67..333.67 rows=472 width=1046) (actual time=5.574..5.938 rows=493 loops=1)                                     |
  ->  Sort  (cost=325.67..329.67 rows=1599 width=1046) (actual time=5.572..5.681 rows=1773 loops=1)                               |
        Sort Key: id, revision_date DESC, revision_id DESC                                                                        |
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1447kB                                                                                    |
        ->  Seq Scan on indicator_revisions  (cost=0.00..240.58 rows=1599 width=1046) (actual time=0.015..2.501 rows=1773 loops=1)|
              Filter: (NOT draft)                                                                                                 |
              Rows Removed by Filter: 269                                                                                         |
Planning Time: 0.151 ms                                                                                                           |
Execution Time: 6.025 ms                                                                                                          |
```

query plan with 64kB of work_mem:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Unique  (cost=0.28..1015.05 rows=472 width=1046) (actual time=0.026..3.834 rows=493 loops=1)                                                                   |
  ->  Index Scan using key_risk_indicators_index on indicator_revisions  (cost=0.28..1011.05 rows=1599 width=1046) (actual time=0.022..3.138 rows=1773 loops=1)|
        Filter: (NOT draft)                                                                                                                                    |
        Rows Removed by Filter: 269                                                                                                                            |
Planning Time: 0.158 ms                                                                                                                                        |
Execution Time: 3.904 ms                                                                                                                                       |
```

2s of difference, 50% faster?!?

PS: I know that in this case in index scan kicks in, but the planner should know better right? If it's better with the index scan why the planner didn't go for it the first time?

Comment: It's 2 **milli**seconds difference not 2 _seconds_. In the future you might also want to run `explain (analyze, buffers)` to see how much I/O the query had to do. Maybe the second run took everything from the cache and that's the main reason for the runtime difference. You should also include the query  in your question

Comment: The choice to use an index is influenced through `random_page_cost`. If that is high, the planner will favor a Seq Scan over an Index Scan

Comment: You can also use [pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) to get more than one sample and [`generate_series(1,1e8,1)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to set up test tables with a bit more rows, to see how things scale.